# How to use linux find command to replace special characters in all file names?

Tags: bash, replace, find, exec

I want to replace all special characters `(i.e. _?:/)(\-\n\t)` in all pdf files' name by a space.

I wasn't able to do that so I just tried to remove them using this command.

For some reasons this command works sometimes for a test case, but not for others. It gives error mv: target is not a directory, and also input and target files' name are the same (if no special char to remove).

```
find .  -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'if="{}"; of=$(echo $if|tr -d '_:-'  ); mv $if $of ;' \;
```

I expect to change filename:

```
    a:bc-de_(fg).pdf
```

To be

```
    a bc de  fg .pdf
```

Comment: See [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) and [BashFAQ #30: "How can I rename all my *.foo files to *.bar, or convert spaces to underscores, or convert upper-case file names to lower case?"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"mv: target is not a directory" is because of the spaces in the file name, and can be fixed by putting file name within double quotes.

Try this

```
find .  -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'if="{}"; of=$(echo $if|tr "()_:-" " " ); mv "$if" "$of" ;' \;
```

Comment: Enclosing $of with quotation helps, but still, mv gives not a dictionary error. When enclosing both $if and $of, it works. Thanks

Comment: Even if you double-quote references to `$if`, this'll still have trouble with filenames that contain double-quotes, dollar signs, backticks, or backslashes, because those aren't safe in the original `if="{}"` assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Just more efficient

```
find ~+ -regextype awk -iregex '.*/[^/]*[-_:()\t][^/]*\.pdf' -exec sh -c 'mv "{}" "`echo "{}"|sed -E "s/[-_:\(\)\t]+/ /g"`"' \;
```

also does rename such a:bc-_:d to 'a bc d'

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use sed:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' sh -c 'mv "$0" "$(sed "s/[-_:()]/ /g" <<< $0)"' {} \;
```

sample files:

```
$ ls
'a:bc-de_(fg).pdf'  'f:sc-de_(fg).pdf' somefile
```

output files:

```
$ ls
'a bc de  fg .pdf'  'f sc de  fg .pdf'   somefile
```